# Google Cloud Compute no storage left

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-persistent-disk

Hi when i try to ssh to google cloud VM instance it doesn't connect and when i check the logs it says there is no storage available.

[image: 1]

but when i connect using google cloud console it connects and when i check the storage there is enough storage

[image: 2]

also one thing my current persistent disk is 20gb but here it shows twice the amount. if anyone can explain me whats going this would help me out a lot

Comment: I think you're confusing cloud shell with a VM. They don't share disk.

Comment: ah ok so your saying that the vm is out of space? @TravisWebb

Answer (score 1):

The output that you are posting is from Cloud Shell [link](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works).

> When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a g1-small Google Compute
>   Engine virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating system.
>   Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session
>   basis. The instance persists while your Cloud Shell session is active;
>   after an hour of inactivity, your session terminates and its VM,
>   discarded. For more on usage quotas, refer to the limitations guide.
>
> With the default Cloud Shell experience, you are allocated with an
>   ephemeral, pre-configured VM and the environment you work with is a
>   Docker container running on that VM. You can also choose to use a
>   custom environment to save your configurations, in which case, your
>   environment will be your very own custom Docker image.
>
> Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as
>   your $HOME directory on the virtual machine instance.

As Travis mentioned you run `df -h --total` in the Cloud Shell storage not the VM.

Here you can find a SO related question with possible solutions to fix your issue.

[Disk is full, and I can't SSH to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126654/disk-is-full-and-i-cant-ssh-to-instance).